# Nothing returned from Elm Http.send - just original model

Tags: json, http, elm

I'm learning Elm and am making fair progress. But I can't get Http.send to work. The expected JSON string wasn't returned from the server, but it works directly in the browser. My JSON decoders look solid and my Http.send is as per the texts I've read. When compiling with --debug, the model isn't changed during a run. I'm green at debugging Elm, so I just created some dummy return models in update to see at which stage it's failing. In the code below, strictly for debugging purposes, I always get back companyTypeList1 ("DIDN'T RUN"), which appears to mean that my Cmd - listCompanyTypes - isn't being called at all. But I don't get any errors. Is there any reason the Cmd would not run or just return the initial model without doing anything? This is Elm 0.18. I can't find any topics on this problem in SO or the web, so I must be doing something stoopid. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import Http exposing (..)
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (..)
import Objects.CompanyTypes.Model exposing (..)
import Objects.CompanyTypes.Msg exposing (..)

update : Msg -> List CompanyType -> ( List CompanyType, Cmd Msg )
update msg companyTypeList =
    let
        companyTypeList1 =
            [ { id = 0, name = "DIDN'T RUN" } ]

        companyTypeList2 =
            [ { id = 0, name = "GOOD RETURN" } ]

        companyTypeList3 =
            [ { id = 0, name = "ERROR RETURN" } ]
    in
        case msg of
            List ->
                ( companyTypeList1, listCompanyTypes )

            ListResult (Ok newCompanyTypeList) ->
                ( companyTypeList2, Cmd.none )

            ListResult (Err _) ->
                ( companyTypeList3, Cmd.none )

listCompanyTypes : Cmd Msg
listCompanyTypes =
    Http.send ListResult (Http.get "http://laserver:8080/company_types" decodeCompanyTypes)

decodeCompanyTypes : Decoder (List CompanyType)
decodeCompanyTypes =
    list decodeCompanyType


decodeCompanyType : Decoder CompanyType
decodeCompanyType =
    map2 CompanyType
        (field "id" int)
        (field "name" string)
```

UPDATE: I read that CORS could be the problem so I'm checking it on my Apache server. I've enabled mod_header and added a 'Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"' entry to my site config. It's not working but I'll fiddle and report back.

Comment: Is there any console output?

Comment: Are you sure that you have wired up the parent of this update function to handle the command that it returns?

Comment: @farmio. No console output. I've been running it straight from file. So I fired up elm-reactor, but still no output. So I compiled with --debug but no output - just the model with "DIDN'T RUN" substituted in the name field.

Comment: @SimonH I think so. I'm calling the update in order to build a ul list of CompanyTypes on screen. I discard the returned Cmd because I don't need it. The modified dummy model that is returned displays fine - I get a ul populated with one "DIDN'T RUN" entry. Just don't get anything from the server. I'm busy checking out CORS to see if that's the problem.

Comment: @user3412006 if you discard the Cmd the Task will not be run. You should `Cmd.map` it to a Msg in the parent. The Cmd has to reach the root Update function declared in the Html.program function.

Comment: @user3412006 if CORS was the problem your browser would probably log an Error to the console.

Comment: @farmio. Ah! Okay. I thought it just ran the listCompanyTypes function from the update. Are your saying it actually passes the whole tuple back to the parent and listCompanyTypes gets called from there?

Comment: @farmio Yeah, I suspected it wasn't CORS because I would have seen some kind of error, even if just in the browser console. Just checking the boxes.

Comment: @user3412006 yes that is what's happening. You have to map it to a Msg so the result can be processed by the right update function (the one emitting listCompanyTypes)

Comment: @farmio Now that you say it, it falls into place. Still getting my head around the Elm Architecture and functional. Thanks a stack - I really appreciate it. I'll close this question.

Comment: @user3412006 -- just to elaborate, `Http.send` returns a `Cmd Msg`, which is a description of work you'd like Elm to do; `send` itself doesn't do that work. However you organize your program, `main` is the only entry point that the Elm runtime has into your program, and so if you want to tell Elm to do some work, you need to give it a command through one of the functions that's hooked up to `main` (either your `init` value or your `update` function). Anywhere else in your program, a `Cmd Msg` is just static data :-)